# Garbage Value Returned For Sum C++

Tags: c++, math, sum, return, double

Okay, so I did some testing to my program here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

void calcTwinkieChange();

int main(){
        calcTwinkieChange();
        return 0;
}

void calcTwinkieChange(){
   const double tCost(3.50);
   const char DL1[3] = "DL", DL2[3] = "Dl", DL3[3] = "dl", DL4[3] = "dL";
   const char QR1[3] = "QR", QR2[3] = "Qr", QR3[3] = "qr", QR4[3] = "qR";
   const char DM1[3] = "DM", DM2[3] = "Dm", DM3[3] = "dm", DM4[3] = "dM";
   const char NK1[3] = "NK", NK2[3] = "Nk", NK3[3] = "nk", NK4[3] = "nK";
   double totalMoney(0), totalChange(0);
   char inTyp[3];
   while(totalMoney < tCost){
        system("CLS");
        cout << "Input \"DL\" for dollar, \"QR\" for quarter, \"DM\" for dimes, and \"NK\" for nickels:" << endl;
      cin >> inTyp;

      if(strncmp(inTyp, DL1, 3) == 0 || strncmp(inTyp, DL2, 3) == 0 || strncmp(inTyp, DL3, 3) == 0 || strncmp(inTyp, DL4, 3) == 0){
         totalMoney += 1.00;
         cout << "Amount: $" << totalMoney << endl;
         system("PAUSE");
      }
      else if(strncmp(inTyp, QR1, 3) == 0 || strncmp(inTyp, QR2, 3) == 0 || strncmp(inTyp, QR3, 3) == 0 || strncmp(inTyp, QR4, 3) == 0){
         totalMoney += 0.25;
         cout << "Amount: $" << totalMoney << endl;
         system("PAUSE");
      }
      else if(strncmp(inTyp, DM1, 3) == 0 || strncmp(inTyp, DM2, 3) == 0 || strncmp(inTyp, DM3, 3) == 0 || strncmp(inTyp, DM4, 3) == 0){
         totalMoney += 0.10;
         cout << "Amount: $" << totalMoney << endl;
         system("PAUSE");
      }
      else if(strncmp(inTyp, NK1, 3) == 0 || strncmp(inTyp, NK2, 3) == 0 || strncmp(inTyp, NK3, 3) == 0 || strncmp(inTyp, NK4, 3) == 0){
         totalMoney += 0.05;
         cout << "Amount: $" << totalMoney << endl;
         system("PAUSE");
      }
      else{
          Beep(1000, 300);
              cout << "Invalid Input, Please Try Again..." << endl;
              system("PAUSE");
      }
   }
   /*
   cout << "Total Cost: " << tCost << " " << totalMoney << " " << totalChange << " ";
   system("PAUSE");
   */
//--- I believe the issue resides on the line bellow.  It may contain an uninitialized variable— somehow. ---
   totalChange = (totalMoney - tCost);
   cout << "Enjoy your deep fried Twinkie..." << endl;
   cout << "Your change: $" << totalChange << endl;
   system("PAUSE");
}
```

The program is intended to take dollars, quarters, dimes and nickels one after the other, until a sum of $3.50 in total is reached, in which the program will return "Enjoy your deep fried Twinkie." and as well return the proper amount of change if applicable.

The program works great and returns change properly, until I entered 35 dimes and got this as my return for change:

[image]  I also believe this same thing occurred when entering 70 nickels, and returned a garbage value.

Any insight to the source of my problem is much appreciated.
*It should also be mentioned that my C++ teacher didn't get this ether, hence I'm here.*

Comment: You should read [What Every Computer Scientiest Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). I do realize that most computer scientist do **not** know any of that stuff. Even if they did know about it at some point, they have since forgotten all about it. It is still relevant, though.

Comment: The Higher Entities have spoken to me.  You will gain much insight by using a magical tool called a *debugger*.

Comment: The Neaderthal's are chanting back.  They say to use *print* statements instead; they like their old ways.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: While that link is a great resource, [a simpler introduction for mere mortals is probably more likely to be read](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: Please include your source code in the question.  Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"e-015" is your clue that the "change" is essentially $0, and that this is just a rounding error.  Your teacher at least needs to learn about rounding errors!  If you have $0.50 or $0.25, this can be represented exactly in binary, but $0.05 will be a repeating fraction in binary and can't be represented exactly...the endless repeating sequence of 00101's will be chopped off after 48 bits or whatever it is. So the nickels will never sum to exactly $3.50.

The solution is to print the answer to only a reasonable number of decimal places, OR to represent everything in cents instead of dollars.

BTW, I think most programmers would prefer this syntax:

const double tCost=3.50;

instead of:

const double tCost(3.50);

Comment: Or `const double tCost{3.50};`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of working with dollar amounts in a `double`, use cents in an `int`. This will eliminate the roundoff error that inevitably creeps in when doing `double` arithmetic, especially repeated subtractions.

The problem is that computers don't work in decimal like humans, they work in binary. A simple decimal such as `0.10` can't be represented exactly in binary but will be a little off (`0.10000000149011612`). As you work with many such numbers the difference will be magnified.